# Asp Menu Bar Shifting up and down with no code difference

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, c#-4.0

I noticed that my ASP menu bar is shifting up and down from the About page to the Home page and I compared the code and there were no differences! I am thinking maybe I have a CSS property that is doing it but I am not sure!?????

Code: Home.aspx:

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head id="Head1"><title>

</title><link href="Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <style type="text/css">
        .style1
        {
            font-size: 26px; 
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .style2
        {
            color: red;
        }
        .txtSize
        {
            Height: 35px;
            Width: 240px; 
            font-weight: bold;
            Font-Size: Medium;
        }
        .btnSize {
            Height: 45px;
            Width: 150px; 
            font-weight: bold;
            Font-Size: Medium;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="Home.aspx" id="Form1">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwULLTE4MzUxNzA1NjUPZBYCZg8PFgQeD19fQW50aVhzcmZUb2tlbgUgZjAxMDQ5OTJmZGU3NDM1M2IwOGJmODJjMzc1OGU3MWUeEl9fQW50aVhzcmZVc2VyTmFtZWVkFgICAw9kFgYCAQ8PFgIeBFRleHQFBEhvbWVkZAIDDw8WAh8CBQlMb2dnZWQgSW5kZAIHD2QWCAIBDw8WAh4HVmlzaWJsZWhkZAIDDw8WAh8CBQdMb2cgT3V0ZGQCCw9kFgICAQ8PFgIfAgUhY3BldGVyc29uIGlzIGN1cnJlbnRseSBsb2dnZWQgaW4uZGQCDQ8PFgIfA2dkZGSevdstBPQu3Rt2jtT28EtIGPu5UIQuxLWCeIBU9ka7YA==" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['Form1'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.Form1;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>



<script src="/WebResource.axd?d=gSrER28sXqMP8fEUoajfSxdNCvQuvyo90E5GWC7tlKPXzEeCq6VpnhXaFhUduhDT2sVCya7P95MYdseTo6Qk66TxTAo4t8gpRhxfEAmqyWU1&amp;t=635589147476784022" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div class="aspNetHidden">

    <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="8D0E13E6" />
    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEdAAMhPZpi8eTtLPeJKtw+QkmB+CHI2KGhrgOke/DbhB4LDdChL5XgpGwrtX4d6Nr6DYZ2+PmP8YijK88yO/QKhFtGL1X04NPfMAQo+XemlgF4Sg==" />
</div>
    <div class="page">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="title">
                <h1>
                    <span id="lblTitle">Home</span><br />
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="loginDisplay">
                <span id="LoginStatus">Logged In</span>
            </div>
            <div class="clear hideSkiplink">
                 <a href="#NavigationMenu_SkipLink"><img alt="Skip Navigation Links" src="/WebResource.axd?d=HI4n-7Ri0rYoMC9nMbHRb5Rq1gRqlKegDUocBvSBAOG7lCnYg2ZeRIT3EUmaldzMTwX7jCRDpuqeXo9fMtXXwn5uigjkDRYYcjvMR1xBFyU1&amp;t=635589147476784022" width="0" height="0" style="border-width:0px;" /></a><div class="menu" id="NavigationMenu">
    <ul class="level1">
        <li><a class="level1" href="Home.aspx">Home</a></li><li><a class="level1" href="About.aspx">About</a></li>
    </ul>
</div><a id="NavigationMenu_SkipLink"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="main">


    <br />
        <input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$btnSubmit" value="Log Out" id="MainContent_btnSubmit" class="btnSize" />
        <br />


       <span id="MainContent_lblMessage"></span>

<br />
<br />
    <a id="MainContent_lnkChangePassword" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$lnkChangePassword&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" style="font-weight:bold;">Change Password</a><br />



        </div>
        <div class="clear">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
    </div>

<script type='text/javascript'>new Sys.WebForms.Menu({ element: 'NavigationMenu', disappearAfter: 500, orientation: 'horizontal', tabIndex: 0, disabled: false });</script></form>
</body>
</html>
```

About.ASPX:

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head id="Head1"><title>
    About Us
</title><link href="Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="About.aspx" id="Form1">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUKMTY1NDU2MTA1Mg9kFgJmDw8WBB4PX19BbnRpWHNyZlRva2VuBSBmMDEwNDk5MmZkZTc0MzUzYjA4YmY4MmMzNzU4ZTcxZR4SX19BbnRpWHNyZlVzZXJOYW1lZWQWAgIDD2QWAgIBDw8WAh4EVGV4dAUFQWJvdXRkZGTgVnK0X4ksUDmmBleUmVlcG4qd/USpQs+XOMcEHWNK3w==" />
</div>


<script src="/WebResource.axd?d=gSrER28sXqMP8fEUoajfSxdNCvQuvyo90E5GWC7tlKPXzEeCq6VpnhXaFhUduhDT2sVCya7P95MYdseTo6Qk66TxTAo4t8gpRhxfEAmqyWU1&amp;t=635589147476784022" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div class="aspNetHidden">

    <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="E809BCA5" />
</div>
    <div class="page">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="title">
                <h1>
                    <span id="lblTitle">About</span><br />
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="loginDisplay">
                <span id="LoginStatus">Not logged in.</span>
            </div>
            <div class="clear hideSkiplink">
                 <a href="#NavigationMenu_SkipLink"><img alt="Skip Navigation Links" src="/WebResource.axd?d=HI4n-7Ri0rYoMC9nMbHRb5Rq1gRqlKegDUocBvSBAOG7lCnYg2ZeRIT3EUmaldzMTwX7jCRDpuqeXo9fMtXXwn5uigjkDRYYcjvMR1xBFyU1&amp;t=635589147476784022" width="0" height="0" style="border-width:0px;" /></a><div class="menu" id="NavigationMenu">
    <ul class="level1">
        <li><a class="level1" href="Home.aspx">Home</a></li><li><a class="level1" href="About.aspx">About</a></li>
    </ul>
</div><a id="NavigationMenu_SkipLink"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="main">

    <h2>
       PC
    </h2>
    <p>
        The Web App was developed in order to better assist meeting our customer needs and provide them with the best quality service.

        <br />
        version: 1.01
    </p>

        </div>
        <div class="clear">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
    </div>

<script type='text/javascript'>new Sys.WebForms.Menu({ element: 'NavigationMenu', disappearAfter: 500, orientation: 'horizontal', tabIndex: 0, disabled: false });</script></form>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Site.css:

```
/* DEFAULTS
----------------------------------------------------------*/

body   
{
    background: #BEDFFF;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Lucida Grande", "Segoe UI", Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    color: #000000;
}

a:link, a:visited
{
    color: #034af3;
}

a:hover
{
    color: #1d60ff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:active
{
    color: #034af3;
}

p
{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    line-height: 1.6em;
}


/* HEADINGS   
----------------------------------------------------------*/

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6
{
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #000000;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    text-transform: none;
    font-weight: 200;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

h1
{
    font-size: 1.6em;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

h2
{
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: 600;
}

h3
{
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

h4
{
    font-size: 1.1em;
}

h5, h6
{
    font-size: 1em;
}

/* this rule styles <h1> and <h2> tags that are the 
first child of the left and right table columns */
.rightColumn > h1, .rightColumn > h2, .leftColumn > h1, .leftColumn > h2
{
    margin-top: 0px;
}


/* PRIMARY LAYOUT ELEMENTS   
----------------------------------------------------------*/

.page
{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.header
{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: #BEDFFF;
    width: 100%;
}

.header h1
{
    font-weight: 700;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
    color: #000000;
    border: none;
    line-height: 2em;
    font-size: 2em;
}

.main
{
    padding: 0px 12px;
    margin: 12px 8px 8px 8px;
    min-height: 420px;
}

.leftCol
{
    padding: 6px 0px;
    margin: 12px 8px 8px 8px;
    width: 200px;
    min-height: 200px;
}

.footer
{
    color: #4e5766;
    padding: 8px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: normal;
}


/* TAB MENU   
----------------------------------------------------------*/

.dynamic

{ width: 100%;}

.menu ul li ul

{display: none;}

.menu ul li

{position: relative;float: left;list-style: none;}

div.menu ul.level3 li.dynamic

{left: 40px;}

div.menu ul.level3 li.dynamic

{right: 40px;}

div.hideSkiplink
{
    background-color:#BEDFFF;
    width:100%;
    height: 100px;
}

div.menu
{
    padding: 4px 0px 4px 8px;
}

div.menu ul
{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: auto;
}

div.menu ul li a, div.menu ul li a:visited
{
    background-color: #8EC5E4;
    border: 2px #315496 solid;
    color: #000000;
    font-size:larger;
    display: block;
    line-height: 2em;
    padding:4px 20px;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    height: 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}

div.menu ul li a:hover
{
    background-color: #B4F7C2;
    color: #465c71;
    text-decoration: none;
}

div.menu ul li a:active
{
    background-color: #465c71;
    color: #cfdbe6;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* FORM ELEMENTS   
----------------------------------------------------------*/

fieldset
{
    margin: 1em 0px;
    padding: 1em;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

fieldset p 
{
    margin: 2px 12px 10px 10px;
}

fieldset.login label, fieldset.register label, fieldset.changePassword label
{
    display: block;
}

fieldset label.inline 
{
    display: inline;
}

legend 
{
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 2px 4px 8px 4px;
}

input.textEntry 
{
    width: 320px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

input.passwordEntry 
{
    width: 320px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

div.accountInfo
{
    width: 42%;
}

/* MISC  
----------------------------------------------------------*/

.clear
{
    clear: both;
}

.title
{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    width: auto;
}

.loginDisplay
{
    font-size: 1.1em;
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #000000;
}

.loginDisplay a:link
{
    color: white;
}

.loginDisplay a:visited
{
    color: white;
}

.loginDisplay a:hover
{
    color: white;
}

.failureNotification
{
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: Red;
}

.bold
{
    font-weight: bold;
}

.submitButton
{
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.loginDiv
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 200px;
    top: 150px;
    height: 18px;
    width: 72px;
}
```

Comment: Please post the content of your Styles/Site.css

Comment: your code giving me the same results with no different between the pages style as you posted

Comment: i suspect the tag `img alt="Skip Navigation Links"`